# Groupby of multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I have

| Process | Assists | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **23d34** | 0 | 13.10.2020 |
| 23d4t | 1 | 14.10.2020 |
| 56z45 | 3 | 13.10.2020 |
| **23d34** | 0 | 13.10.2020 |

I want to groupby the Column "Process" by its value. If I use this function:

```
df_new = df.groupby(['Process'])['Assists'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))).reset_index()
```

it looks like this

| Process | Assists |
| --- | --- |
| 23d34 | 0,0 |
| 23d4t | 1 |
| 56z45 | 3 |

My problem is, that I still need the "Date" column to be able to filter after dates. The "Dates" for the processes must be the same. So it would be nice just to "merge" or "groupby " the dates too.

I want

| Process | Assists | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23d34 | 0,0 | 13.10.2020 |
| 23d4t | 1 | 14.10.2020 |
| 56z45 | 3 | 13.10.2020 |

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group by `Process` **and** `Date`, try:

```py
df_new = df.groupby(["Process", "Date"], as_index=False)["Assists"].apply(
    lambda x: ",".join(x.astype(str))
)

print(df_new)
```

Prints:

```
  Process        Date Assists
0   23d34  13.10.2020     0,0
1   23d4t  14.10.2020       1
2   56z45  13.10.2020       3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an aggregate function : `min`, `max`, `first`, `last` :

```
df_new = df.astype({'Assists':'str'})
    .groupby('Process',as_index=False)
    .agg({'Assists':','.join,'Date':'min'}))
```